# CMake: Could not find Boost (missing: serialization)

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I am cursed with the willingness to create an application for all OS.

Unfortunately, this includes using Windows.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(Odin)

include_directories(Odin/engine)
include_directories(Odin/uci)
include_directories(Odin/util)

# add our cmake modules under cmake/
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")

#AddBOOST
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED YES)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS NO)


find_package(Boost 1.74.0 REQUIRED serialization)

#ENDBOOST

message(STATUS "---------------------")
message(STATUS "Boost_FOUND: ${Boost_FOUND}")
message(STATUS "Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS: ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
message(STATUS "Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS: ${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS}")
message(STATUS "Boost_LIBRARIES: ${Boost_LIBRARIES}")
message(STATUS "---------------------")

# Include CPM dependency manager
include(CPM)

# enable testing
enable_testing()

# Pull doctest using CPM
cpmaddpackage("gh:onqtam/doctest#2.4.5")

# add the CMake modules for automatic test discovery so we can use
# doctest_discover_tests() CMake
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${doctest_SOURCE_DIR}/scripts/cmake"
        ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})

add_executable(Odin
        Odin/engine/Odin.cc
        Odin/main.cc
        Odin/engine/Board.cc
        Odin/engine/Figure.cc
        Odin/util/Utility.cc
        Odin/engine/Node.cc
        Odin/engine/Link.cc
        Odin/engine/Odin.h
        Odin/engine/Board.h
        Odin/engine/Figure.h
        Odin/util/Utility.h
        Odin/engine/Node.h
        Odin/engine/Link.h
        )

target_link_libraries(Odin PRIVATE Boost::serialization)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "-O3 -march=native")
```

this cmake does not work on Windows:

The error reads:

`Could NOT find Boost (missing serialization) (found 1.74.0, minimum required is "1.74.0")`

If I look into the folder, there is a serialization folder. I also tried different boost versions and different IDEs (VS 2019 + CLION).

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Its probably the compiled library file it can't find. Tools like [conan](https://conan.io/) will make your life easier

Comment: Hmm, I compiled as instructed from Boost.
Does the same version in "found" and "minimum required" mean that this is not the issue?

Comment: It's found the headers but not the libraries, the error message isn't great

Comment: The answer is to compile using static linking -.-